# When to use Multinomial Naive Bayes?

Tags: naive-bayes-classifier, machine-learning-model

I am working on a text classification problem, and plan on using Naive Bayes based model.

In which cases should I consider using Multinomial Naive Bayes?

Answer (score 1):

For Text classification Multinomial Naive bayes is a good choice to start with.

We can start with MNB, 
when

```
1. There is no dependence between the predictors
2. Good if class is not unblanced
```

(Here is an approach to handle unbalanced data with [MNB](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf) )

I would start with bag of words and then TFIDF vectors to check the model performance before moving further.